# Warn if post contains unescaped non-HTML and disallowed HTML tags

Tags: feature-request

I think that before a user posts a question or answer, the system should warn if the post contains non-HTML tags (and disallowed HTML tags) that may be invisible when displayed. For example, I [edited this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5842237/revisions) because it looked like something was missing:

```
The error is in .
```

As it turned out, it had a hidden tag that clarified the meaning somewhat:

```
The error is in <ImageView>.
```

This went unnoticed for over a year before I edited it. I hope a warning like this will help reduce the number of post issues like this, since the warning will alert the user, say, that the unescaped tag should be wrapped `like this`.

Comment: Isn't it just as big of a problem if the OP is trying to talk about HTML and it's not going to display correctly?

Comment: Seems like the rare case where they didn't use backticks or `<code>`. Usually users abuse those features...

Comment: Happens quite often with generic types in C#.

Comment: @CodesInChaos truth. An easy first pass at this feature would be to check the post for the text `Enumerable<` not contained in code formatting...

Comment: happens a lot with people trying to post XML data, not knowing it should go in a code block

Comment: @AakashM That doesn't account for every other type of generic type, including user-defined ones. Better to look for matched `<` and `>` with a maximum length

Answer (score 8):

Merely non-HTML tags wouldn't suffice. If this was implemented it should be any tags that aren't allowed in posts like `<form>` and `<div>`. I see people do this all the time:

> I want the  to change depending on the  value.

Source:

> `I want the <select> to change depending on the <input> value`.

I habitually check the post source by clicking [edit] whenever I see an awkward sentence like that.

One side of me wants to disagree with this request, since it should be pretty obvious there's a mistake if you actually preview your post before hitting submit, which you should, always. I'm not sure if this would encourage laziness.

On the other hand, I see a lot of posts about HTML get downvoted along with *"Code? What code?"* comments because the code is totally hidden. The burden is on the poster really, but maybe a warning would be a good thing for overall quality and would help newer users get used to formatting correctly.

**Possible alternative solution**: Would it make more sense just to output the brackets on disallowed tags as entities, so that they appear? For instance if I typed `<input>` without formatting it as code, it would appear as <input>. It would still be unformatted, but better than being invisible. Is there any point in hiding disallowed tags in the first place?

Comment: +1 for the alternative - if it's not a recognised token, escape html entities.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you reject some content that looks like a tag, output it with encoded entities in red. Something like `<span class="invalid-html">&lt;div&gt;</span>`.

Comment: I like the idea but I suspect people would use this as a different way of formatting their posts/highlighting things.