# Could angle brackets be escaped for everything not on a permitted HTML tag whitelist?

Tags: feature-request, tags, code-formatting

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618589/how-can-i-fix-a-pinax-0-7-based-social-project-with-model-validation-errors), I noticed that the code I had pasted in a `<pre>` (should I really be going through the manual labor to indent four lines) wasn't displaying crucial parts of the raw source.

They were angle bracket-delimited bits of Python error-code: to render `<class 'taggit.models.TaggedItem'>` I had to escape the opening bracket and give `&lt;class 'taggit.models.TaggedItem'>` — take a wild guess what I did to display the latter. 
My browser, Chrome, originally saw an unrecognized `class` tag, and like a good browser ignored it without display.

I know that limited HTML is permitted, but could angle brackets be escaped for code not on a whitelist of permitted HTML tags, including all tags that are not any form of valid HTML tags?

Comment: @downvoter, read the question, this is a legitimate question for meta.

Comment: @ryan: That has nothing to do with downvotes. Neither on the main site nor hear on Meta.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby yes I know, downvotes are for disagreeing, but who would disagree with this? the editor sucks in a lot of different ways. why would you not want the editor fixed to do more for you automatically ??

Comment: @ryan: Downvotes are different here on Meta. Someone doesn't see a need for changing the formatting, it's a *vote* on the feature request.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ... le sigh, I know how it works, as it was this wasn't tagged feature request, I changed the tag, it was tagged as a bug when it was downvoted.

Comment: @ryan: You can still vote for it not being a bug in that case..

Comment: @ryan: [You might want to read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74559/is-it-now-discouraged-to-ask-for-reasons-for-downvotes-as-a-comment).

Comment: @ryan: Also, maybe someone does not agree that there is something to fix or implement (f.e. do it right and it will work).

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I have read that... and I didn't ask for comments... where did I ask the downvoter to comment?

Comment: @ryan: Yes, you instead harassed the voter...that's just as pointless.

Comment: I don't understand the question. When writing HTML-tags in a code block, these are rendered instead of interpreted - even without escaping them. Like this `<b>This is not bold code</b>`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Spontifixus If you go to the question and click on "edit", you'll see that it's actually not a code block but a `<pre>` block.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170959/warn-if-post-contains-unescaped-non-html-and-disallowed-html-tags

Comment: @Juhana Having inline tags is no problem, when using the default (markdown) way of including code. 4 blanks or a backtick...

Comment: @Spontifixus Yes, that is correct. And the OP asked this question because he *didn't* use the default way to include code.

Comment: @Juhana what he didn't mention in his question...

Comment: @Spontifixus Of course not. If he had known about the "correct" way to format code he wouldn't have had the problem in the first place.

Comment: @Juhana good point...

Comment: @JonathanHayward I just now noticed the "should I go through the manual labor" part -- no, you shouldn't. There's a button in the toolbar you can use or press ctrl/cmd-K to format code. No need to manually type in the spaces, and it's even easier than writing the `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `<pre>` to format code. Indent with four spaces or highlight the text and click on the "code sample" button in the editor (icon with curly brackets).

`<pre>` preserves tags (and SO software proceeds to immediately strip them out) but actual markdown code formatting automatically encodes `<`, `>` and other characters to HTML character entities.

---

Demo (click on "edit" to see the source):

`<pre>`

```
Hello World!
```

Markdown formatting:

```
<strong>Hello</strong> <em>World!</em>
```